# Android - Can't access onSuccess of callback after login with Facebook in fragment

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments, callback

I have **successfully logged in facebook**. But, I can't access **token or user profile from onSuccess method of callback**. I have added callbackManager.onActivityResult in onActivityResult. I can login, but I can't get access token id and user profile

Main.java

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

AccountView.java (Fragment and my error location)

```
 public class AccountView extends Fragment {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account, container, false);
        setupView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void setupView(View view) {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.widget_facebook_button);
        callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            //ERROR
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                //ERROR - I can't get access token and user name
                Log.d("facebook id", accessToken.getApplicationId());
                Log.d("profile name", profile.getFirstName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

        }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }
        };
        facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fragment override `onActivityResult()` as you did the same in activity.
Like :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Add this on Activity :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.i("login","success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i("login","cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.i("login","error");
        }
    });
```

Then, remove registration callback from facebook button :

```
facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
```